# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'install')

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, npm-install

What does this error mean and why does it sometimes happen?

> VM3327 vue.esm.js:5829 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'install') 
> at Vue.use (VM3327 vue.esm.js:5829:31) 
> at eval (VM3493 index.js:10:45) 
> at ./src/router/index.js (VM3317 chat.js:173:1) 
> at **webpack_require** (VM3317 chat.js:1973:42) 
> at eval (VM3326 main.js:5:65) 
> at ./src/main.js (VM3317 chat.js:162:1) 
> at **webpack_require** (VM3317 chat.js:1973:42) 
> at VM3317 chat.js:2037:37 
> at VM3317 chat.js:2039:12 Vue.use @   VM3327 vue.esm.js:5829 eval @   VM3493 index.js:10 ./src/router/index.js    @   VM3317 chat.js:173 
> **webpack_require**   @   VM3317 chat.js:1973 eval    @   VM3326 main.js:5 ./src/main.js  @   VM3317 chat.js:162 
> **webpack_require**   @   VM3317 chat.js:1973 (anonymous) @   VM3317 chat.js:2037 (anonymous) @   VM3317 chat.js:2039

I'm using vuejs in a django project.

***package.json***

````json
{
  "name": "vue-chat-app-two",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "## Project setup ``` yarn install ```",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot",
    "start": "concurrently \"python3 manage.py runserver\" \"npm run dev\""
  },
  "main": "babel.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.30.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-native-websocket": "^2.0.15",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.2",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^15.10.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
    "webpack": "^5.86.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^1.8.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC"
}
````

When I do in vuejs terminal: `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`
I get something like this:

> [webpack-cli] Error:
>
> Vue packages version mismatch:
>
> - vue@3.3.4 (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue/index.js)
> - vue-template-compiler@2.7.14 (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)
>
> This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same
> version for both. If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update
> vue-template-compiler. If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify,
> re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to
> the latest.
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:10:9)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at loadFromContext (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/compiler.js:30:10)
> at loadTemplateCompiler (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/compiler.js:37:12)
> at exports.resolveCompiler (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/compiler.js:25:23)
> at VueLoaderPlugin.apply (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin-webpack5.js:144:22)
> at createCompiler (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:73:12)
> at create (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:134:16)
> at webpack (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:142:47)
> at WebpackCLI.f [as webpack] (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:72:16)
> at WebpackCLI.createCompiler (.../vue-chat-app-two/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1785:29)
> ```

---

I tried **@Ewan Reveille's** answer:

I changed `vue-template-compiler`to 3.3.4 instead of 2.7.14, then I did `npm install`.

I got something like this in the terminal:

> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving:
> vue-chat-app-two@0.1.0 npm WARN Found: vue-template-compiler@2.7.14
> npm WARN node_modules/vue-template-compiler npm WARN   dev
> vue-template-compiler@"^3.3.4" from the root project npm WARN   1 more
> (@vue/cli-service) npm WARN  npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peerOptional vue-template-compiler@"^2.0.0" from
> @vue/cli-service@5.0.8 npm WARN node_modules/@vue/cli-service npm WARN
> dev @vue/cli-service@"~5.0.0" from the root project npm WARN   4 more
> (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...) npm WARN ERESOLVE
> overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving:
> vue-chat-app-two@0.1.0 npm WARN Found: vue-template-compiler@2.7.14
> npm WARN node_modules/vue-template-compiler npm WARN   dev
> vue-template-compiler@"^3.3.4" from the root project npm WARN   1 more
> (@vue/cli-service) npm WARN  npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peerOptional vue-template-compiler@"^2.0.0" from
> @vue/cli-service@5.0.8 npm WARN node_modules/@vue/cli-service npm WARN
> dev @vue/cli-service@"~5.0.0" from the root project npm WARN   4 more
> (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...) npm WARN ERESOLVE
> overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving:
> vue-chat-app-two@0.1.0 npm WARN Found: vue-template-compiler@2.7.14
> npm WARN node_modules/vue-template-compiler npm WARN   dev
> vue-template-compiler@"^3.3.4" from the root project npm WARN   1 more
> (@vue/cli-service) npm WARN  npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peerOptional vue-template-compiler@"^2.0.0" from
> @vue/cli-service@5.0.8 npm WARN node_modules/@vue/cli-service npm WARN
> dev @vue/cli-service@"~5.0.0" from the root project npm WARN   4 more
> (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...) npm ERR! code
> ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for
> vue-template-compiler@^3.3.4. npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or
> one of your dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package
> version that doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> .../.npm/_logs/2023-06-08T10_51_43_433Z-debug-0.log

---

### Update 9 June 2023

***webpack.config.js:***

```js
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/js'),
    publicPath: '/static/js/',
    filename: 'chat.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({ filename: '../vue-chat-app-two/webpack-stats.json' }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: false
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
    extensions: ['.*','.js','.vue','.json']
  },
};
```

Comment: *vuejs* → *[Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js)*. *django* → *[Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)*.

Comment: It is unlikely that the last part appeared like that in the terminal. Aren't there some newlines in there?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's when I did: `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`

Comment: I added `.../` manually since right now I'm anonymous user.

Answer (score 1):

The error probably comes from the incompatibility between Vue.js version and its template compiler version. To correct that, you should modify the line : "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14", in "devDependencies" by the line "vue-template-compiler": "^3.3.4",.
Then, launch the command "npm install" in the terminal to update your dependencies.
I hope this helped !

Comment: version 3.3.4 of **vue-template-compiler** doesn't work.